# Revoke Apple Developer Certificate while an app is already deployed in the appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, certificate

if i already have an app available in the appstore. Would it be okay to revoke my certificate and generate a new one? Will that affect the app already deployed?

Comment: Why upvotes ? what research effort this question shows ?